# Blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have a Node JS app which acts as server and processes the data through **POST** request and running on other port.On the other part i have another jQuery web application which acts as client and sends the post request to Node JS app.

When i try to POST the data from jQuery client, it is throwing error as below

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/data' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response
```

Below is my Node JS and i have added the any domain to access Node JS app

```
// Starting the App Server on Port 3000
app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Server running on port http://localhost:3000");
});

// set headers for allowing cross domain access
//Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

My client jquery looks like below which post the data to Node JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
console.log(" Entered inside click ");



$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '{"data":"<div>Some raw data pushed to node url</div>"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(" Data Received ");
        $("#content").append("Data received");
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log(" Error while connecting for data");
    },
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/data',
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ CORS library.  It is common place to see the middleware set above 
`app.use(function (req, res, next) {`

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from the request. The header should only be included in the response. To me it seems like since it is not in the list of [allowed headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header) and you don't specifically allow it in your Node app it causes the issue.